# crontab doesn't seem to work and makes different schedule in cron.d!

Tags: bash, scripts, backup, cron

`sudo crontab -e` lets me edit the crontab, and I put in this:

```
# Hourly backup
0 * * * * rsnapshot hourly

# Daily backup
0 2 * * * rsnapshot daily

# Weekly backup
0 4 * * 6 rsnapshot weekly
```

And it was not working. I changed it to use full path for rsnapshot, still not working. I had read something somewhere about cron.d, so I went to /etc/cron.d/ and found a file called rsnapshot. It looked like this:

```
#0 */4      * * *       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot hourly
#30 3   * * *       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
#0  3   * * 1       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly
#30 2   1 * *       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot monthly
```

Strange, I never had a monthly backup via rsnapshot that I know of. Anyway, uncomment the ones I need.

I added a line for testing via `sudo crontab -e` but `cat /etc/cron.d/rsnapshot` did not reflect any changes, but the test process (echo to a .txt) seems to work. Why isn't my backup working? When I do `sudo rsnapshot hourly` in the terminal, it seems to work fine.

Also, why is the schedule different from the one I put? Is this file even related to the crontab?

Comment: It seems the /etc/rsnapshot.conf had syntax errors because of whitespace. That is cleared up, but still not why there is a difference in schedule times between the two files.

Answer (score 0):

"System" cron jobs are run through the `/etc/crontab` file, not through the `root` user's `crontab` file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`, which is what `sudo crontab -e` edits. `/etc/crontab` on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 system is (Note the informative `#comments`):

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Comment: What is the `/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot` file for? Why does it have a different schedule than the crontab I made with `sudo crontab -e` ?

Comment: AskUbuntu is not a conversation system, it's a Q&A system. Other users can search the Questions, and may find answers to their problems thereby. Asking a second question, as you just did, hides the second question from the indexing system. If one were to produce a brilliant answer to your second question, it wouldn't be indexed, either. That's why most AskUbuntu users refuse to answer second questions. If you have a question that you cannot answer by reading files on your system to understand how `root`'s crontab is handled, ask a new question.

Comment: "Why does it have a different schedule than the crontab I made with sudo crontab -e" was part of my original question... ignore the first part of my comment if you want

Answer (score 0):

I was confusing things. The /etc/cron.d/rsnapshot file came with the rsnapshot package, it was not created by the crontab command (hence, why it had a different schedule). It is not necessary to use the crontab command at all, simply edit the /etc/cron.d/rsnapshot, this works fine.